# How to write a common code block which can be used across multiple columns in index method of activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Lets say I drive all the required values(for multiple columns) in a hash.I want to use this hash across multiple columns. I don't want to repeat the code for each column.Where and how to write this common code ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the configuration hash you want to use? And you want to use it for the `index` page of a model?

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides a method [`with_options`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-with_options) that might be a solution:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  index do
    column(:id)

    with_options class: "highlight" do |opts|
      opts.column(:name)
      opts.column(:email)
      opts.column(:last_ip)
    end

    column(:created_at)
  end
end
```